# Does a view needs any action to be updated or even it needs some time to that?

Tags: mysql, database

I created a view that should have only the rows that date field is between a range. When I use a php page to fetch the data with some where conditions, it returns no results. But if I use "select * from", through phpMyAdmin it returns all data and then, if I try to fetch again with my php page(the same code with conditions that I tried before), it works properly. The impression I have is the view only updates if I do a "select * from" query. Have in mind that this view has only 4 rows for tests purposes.

My view: (fields agendadoEm and agendadoPara has type datetime)

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Agendamento AS (
SELECT agendamentos.id as id, agendamentos.userid as userid, agendamentos.paciente as paciente,agendamentos.agendadoEm as agendadoEm, agendamentos.agendadoPara as agendadoPara,
agendamentos.confirmado as confirmado, agendamentos.notificada as notificada,usuarios.contaTipo as contaTipo, profissionais.profissao as profissao

    FROM agendamentos

LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id=agendamentos.userid
LEFT JOIN profissionais ON profissionais.userid=agendamentos.userid

WHERE (agendamentos.confirmado=0 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,agendamentos.agendadoEm,NOW())<35) OR

(agendamentos.confirmado=1 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),agendamentos.agendadoPara)>1));
```

The query that I performing with my php page:

```
SELECT vw_Agendamento.id as id, vw_Agendamento.userid as userid, 
vw_Agendamento.paciente as paciente,vw_Agendamento.agendadoPara as agendadoPara,usuarios.nome as nome,
usuarios.contaTipo as contaTipo, profissionais.sexo as sexo, profissionais.profissao as profissaoId,
tipoProfissionalPF.tipo as profissao,tipoProfissionalPF.urlprefix as urlprefix, tipoProfissionalPJ.tipo as estabelecimento,
tipoProfissionalPJ.urlprefix as clinprefix,empresaDados.nomeFantasia as nomeFantasia 
FROM vw_Agendamento 
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id=vw_Agendamento.userid 
LEFT JOIN profissionais ON profissionais.userid=vw_Agendamento.userid 
LEFT JOIN empresaDados ON empresaDados.userid=vw_Agendamento.userid 
LEFT JOIN tipoProfissionalPF ON tipoProfissionalPF.id=profissionais.profissao 
LEFT JOIN tipoProfissionalPJ ON tipoProfissionalPJ.id=empresaDados.tipoProfissionalPJ 

WHERE vw_Agendamento.paciente=? AND vw_Agendamento.confirmado=0
```

Doesn't matter how many times I run this query, it doesn't return any results. But after a "select * from vw_Agendamento", I open the same php page and it is fetching the properly data. Do you have any idea what is happening?

Comment: _How much time can a view take to update its data?..._ There is no flat answer to this question

Comment: yeah, I just updated the question... read again, please.

Comment: _read again, please..._ Sorry but it is unclear what you are trying to ask

Comment: @B001ᛦ the question is when I try to perform a select with conditions, the query returns nothing but if I "select * from" it and then, perform the select with conditions again it works. It seems that the view needs to be entirely selected to get updated

Comment: It could be that when you reference the view directly, it is caching the content and then just using it.  Have you tried creating the view with algorithm = temptable (CREATE ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE VIEW view_name ...)?  This will tell mysql to first fetch view data into a temp table and then join it to your sql. Note there will a performance hit  to build the temp table. If that works, you could try to see what causes your original view not to work as you had it. I think it may have to do with outer  joins to usuarios and profissionais both in the view and your query. But that is just a guess.